# How to get the complete URL of a media in Django Rest views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with images/media/files in this view and I wrote this view for the article Model to do some job:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def article_grid_list(request):
    # fetched data from the database
    data = Articles.objects.all().order_by("-created_date")[:11]
    pinned_article = Articles.objects.get(pinned=True)

    # serialized data
    pinned_data = ArticlesSerializer(pinned_article)
    horizontal_data = ArticlesSerializer(data[:3], many=True)
    small_data = ArticlesSerializer(data[3:8], many=True)
    card_data = ArticlesSerializer(data[8:], many=True)

    final_data = {
        "pinned":pinned_data.data,
        "horizontal": horizontal_data.data,
        "small": small_data.data,
        "card": card_data.data
    }
```

when I print the result of this request, I get `cover` field like this: `"cover": "/media/article/artice_cover_NkOUuZ7vH3zEejCgV.jpg",`

but I want the image URL with the hostname

when I write this function like ModelViewSet I get the absolute URL of the  `cover` field and I want to get the absolute URL of the image (hostname + image path) in every request

modelViewSet example :

```
class ArticleGridList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Articles.objects.all().order_by("-created_date")
    serializer_class = ArticlesSerializer
```

I expect this:
`"cover": "http://localhost:8000/media/article/artice_cover_NkOUuZ7vH3zEejCgV.jpg"`

my app urls.py file :

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('articles', ArticlesViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
  path("article-grid-list/", article_grid_list)
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send `context = {'request':request}` in serializer like this ...

#### Way - 1

```
# serialized data
pinned_data = ArticlesSerializer(pinned_article,context = {'request':request})
horizontal_data = ArticlesSerializer(data[:3], many=True,context = {'request':request})
small_data = ArticlesSerializer(data[3:8], many=True,context = {'request':request})
card_data = ArticlesSerializer(data[8:], many=True,context = {'request':request})
```

#### way  - 2 (for applying this method you need to add context = {'request':request}` in serializer like the above method.

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cover = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_cover(self,obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return str(request.build_absolute_uri(obj.cover.url))
```

Comment: thank you, way one worked for me ( i dont tested way two)

what's the reason? why should i pass request to serializer?

Comment: Because the request has a full path of the Project URL, I mean has the absolute URL of the project